# ref to 'static does not live long enough?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing, borrow

Consider next code:

```rust
fn get_ref<'a, R>(slice: &'a Vec<i32>, f: fn(&'a Vec<i32>) -> R) -> R
where
    R: 'a,
{
    f(slice)
}

fn main() {
    let v = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    let iter = get_ref(&v, |x| x.iter().skip(1).take(2));

    println!("{:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

I create some `static` variable, then apply some function to its reference and get a result.
It seems to work totally fine. At least it successfully compiles.

Now I am trying to add next level of abstraction. And things are getting weird...

```rust
fn owned<'a, R>(owner: Vec<i32>, f: fn(&'a Vec<i32>) -> R)
where
    R: 'a,
{
    let _ = get_ref(&owner, f); // error occurs here
    // `owner` does not live long enough.
}

// get_ref is the same as in the first example
fn get_ref<'a, R>(slice: &'a Vec<i32>, f: fn(&'a Vec<i32>) -> R) -> R
where
    R: 'a,
{
    f(slice)
}

fn main() {
    let v = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    owned(v, |x| x.iter().skip(1).take(2));
}
```

For me it looks like pretty the same code. But Rust fails to compile it. I really don't understand why this is happening and how should I rewrite my code to compile.

Comment: Generics are chosen at the callsite. While `O` may live for `'static`, its borrow only lives for the lifetime of the function, so if `'a` is longer than the lifetime of the function, it fails, which is why you get the error.

Comment: Then why it works in the first example?

Comment: In the first example, the reference comes from outside the function, which means that the borrow can outlive the scope of the function.

Comment: In the second example reference comes from outside the function too. `owned` owns the value in the second example exactly like `main` owns `v` in the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine if I decide to call the function `owned<'static, i32>(Vec<i32>, foo)` with `foo` defined as:

```
fn foo(vec: &'static Vec<i32>) -> i32 { ... }
```

This satisfies the bounds for `owned`, since `i32: 'static`. However this means that you *must* have a static reference to call `f`, but `owner` does not live forever, since it is destroyed at the end of `owned`.

One way to fix it is to use the following:

```
fn owned<R>(owner: Vec<i32>, f: for<'a> fn(&'a Vec<i32>) -> R) {
    let _ = get_ref(&owner, f);
}
```

It says that `f` must be callable with *any* lifetime, rather than just some specific lifetime. However, this has the consequence that `R` cannot borrow from the argument, since `R` is declared in a larger scope than `'a`. There isn't any way to fix that while keeping the generics as is.

---

This answer was taken from my response to [this thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/trying-understand-functions-lifetimes/55941/3) on URLO.